# Driving Capacitive Load

Tags: switching, load, capacitive

I did a bistable multivibrator drive NPN mosfet using timer55 and my mosfet drive power LED. Our Load has 3 circuit stage which are emc filter + smps circuit + power Led. I have a problem at that time my mosfet turn off. When mosfet turn off a clicker happens on my Led. Large capacitive loads are discharhing and mosfet behaves like turning on. I dont know how to handle this problem and want to know are there anybody to had this problem ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fexzwj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried you illustrate my circuit in your mind.

Comment: What are the values of your capacitors? Try placing a diode across L1 with the cathode connected to C1 and the anode to C2.  Your FET gate needs a pull-down resistor (gate to source) if you don't have one, otherwise it can float on easily.

Comment: I tried to put resistor  from gate to ground but it doesnt matter.  Two 47uF and two inductor at uH levels i didnt look actually. There is something need take attention; when below 24Volts smps draws 20-30 mA more than nominal voltages which is 28VDC and flicker dissapared.

Comment: Diode like 1N4007 or schottky ?  @JohnD And if i ask you, can u draw what  i have to do and explain the reason to put these diodes.

Comment: I am not sure why you need the PI filter (CLC).  The MOSFET is not driving a lot of current.  Can you eliminate C1 and L and place C2 near LED.

Comment: To eliminate emc problems. Automotive standarts are to heavy. Btw this current draws from input of smps, power led draws 600mA at output.

Comment: @RobB. is there any method to drain this discharge currents safely ?

Comment: Ismail - your problem is L1 and C2.  They are oscillating when you turn off the MOSFET.  That oscillation can couple back to the gate and turn it back on which is why John D suggested adding a gate resistor to ground.   I work in automotive and we wouldn't add this type of filter to a resistive load like LED.  Can you just use C2 near LED?

Comment: Firstly i will try to put suitable resistor to gate . I'm gonna put 4k7 ohm or smt like that. I understand you but a smps circuit drives the led and it is switched by 500khz one and only use C2 can make a problem at EMC test ? this product gonna go EMC. @RobB.

Comment: I can not put C2 near to LED because emc,smps driver and led connected with small cables each others in design. Emc and smps board are seperate. It is gonna be problem ?

Comment: Can you put a 1 ohm resistor in series with C2?  YOu need to dampen this oscillation.

Comment: okey i will try this also. Below 24VDC smps draws little bit more current (20-30mA) from input and its enough for capacitors and flickers dissappare. Above 24-36VDC continues increasingly because current is not enough. @RobB.

Comment: You can also try a small resistor in series with L1 to dampen the circuit.

Comment: to put a diode across L1 that mentioned above can make a solution ? @RobB.

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: okey i will inform you about results. Thanks your advice sir.